# multiqc on RSeQC clipping_profiles

Tags: python, workflow, integration, snakemake

The following snakemake code fails to produce multiqc output although it does for orther RSeQC tools including geneBody_coverage, junction_saturation, and read_distribution (removed here for clarity)

```
rule rseqc_cliping_profile:
    """
    Run RSeQC on merged bam files
    """
    input:
        bam = "results/mappings/{smp}_mappings.bam"
    output:
        pdf3 = "results/rseqc2/{smp}.clipping_profile.R1.pdf",
        pdf4 = "results/rseqc2/{smp}.clipping_profile.R2.pdf",
        xls = "results/rseqc2/{smp}.clipping_profile.xls"
    shell: """
        mkdir -p intermediate/rseqc2
        # Run clipping_profile.py
        clipping_profile.py -i {input.bam} \
        -q 30 \
        -s PE \
        -o intermediate/rseqc2/{wildcards.smp} \
        && cp -f intermediate/rseqc2/{wildcards.smp}.clipping_profile.R1.pdf {output.pdf3} \
        && cp -f intermediate/rseqc2/{wildcards.smp}.clipping_profile.R2.pdf {output.pdf4} \
        && cp -f intermediate/rseqc2/{wildcards.smp}.clipping_profile.xls {output.xls}
        """
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

the results in intermediate/rseqc2 are of the kind (S12 only here):

```
S12.clipping_profile.r
S12.clipping_profile.R1.pdf
S12.clipping_profile.R2.pdf
S12.clipping_profile.xls

multiqc -f -i "RSeQC" -o intermediate/multiqc_rseqc2 -n multiqc_rseqc2 intermediate/rseqc2

[INFO   ]         multiqc : This is MultiQC v1.6
[INFO   ]         multiqc : Template    : default
[INFO   ]         multiqc : Report title: RSeQC
[INFO   ]         multiqc : Searching 'intermediate/rseqc2'
[WARNING]         multiqc : No analysis results found. Cleaning up..
[INFO   ]         multiqc : MultiQC complete
```

It is not a snakemake issue!

Although clipping_profile is in my multiqc config yaml, it seems not fit to find the clipping_profile data for plotting.

The xls file are in fact tsv files in disguise; renaming them .txt or .tsv does not improve the odds.

Comment: When you say "code fails to produce multiqc output", does it mean snakemake completes fine but the output files pdf3, pdf4 and xls are not there at the end of the excution or snakemake fails with some error? If the latter, can you post the error message?

Comment: I modified the code and it worked (adding it above), I am still very confused when and not to use     shadow: "minimal" and if using it where to find the results in order to move them elsewhere. Thanks for your help

Comment: my mistake, multiqc does not find information on a folder produced by rseqc clipping-profile. Please see added code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MultiQC documentation on RSeQC support](https://multiqc.info/docs/#rseqc) shows that MultiQC does not support that particular tool (`clipping_profile`), but it does support the others you mentioned.